# What solutions are there for a date picker on a responsive website?

Tags: mobile, input, dates, input-fields, html5

We're working on a website that is responsive.
So my question is: What about datepickers. If we choose normal datepickers 
Jquery Mobile date pickers don't look good on the full blow template.
And normal date pickers don't really work on mobile browsers.

What I would like to have is

- HTML Input field date for Mobile / Tablet
- A good JS datepicker for my website on mouse devices

Is that possible to have different pickers depending on the device I'm using?

Comment: I think you should rephrase this question. For instance, you don't specify what it is you want out of this date picker exactly, only that you think JQuery Mobiles offer doesn't "look good".

Comment: Are you asking if we know of an existing jQuery / JS datepicker to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a different control for different devices as long as it provides the same functionality and blends in with the platform. When this increases userexperience, you should implement that.

So that answers the UX-part of the question.

On the how-part: Look at the `@media` [specification of W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). I would suggest stackoverflow.com itself to aswer questions about implementation. A starting point would be this: http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Comment: *"You can certainly use a different control for different devices. As this increases userexperience, you should implement that."* I'm not sure I follow how providing totally different functionality on all devices increases user experience. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not totally different experiences, a different control better suited to the device the user is using. In the example of the TS a datecontrol on a website at a laptop is a different expectations than on a mobile phone. They use different controls, but have the same functionality. And in blends in better with the environment and expected behaviour.

Comment: So... how do you distinguish a user using a Windows 8 system on a (touch) tablet and one using a mouse? Keep in mind that the two can be the same device.